# Converting ASCII file to shapefile in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, arcgis-9.3

I am trying to convert ascii  to shapefile I have huge points, latitide, longitude and elevations, I want to use geoprocessing tool also to convert this please let me know if anything is avalible.

I have text file contains longitude, latitude and elevation points I want to convert from the text file to shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1.

I have downloaded a tool asciitoshape but its not working properly, GUI for ascii to shape file is working, but gp.ascii2shape is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Please edit the question to describe the error.

Comment: If you are trying to convert a table of XYZ values into a POINT dataset rather than a RASTER dataset then you should use the Make XY Event Layer tool then export that to a shapefile.

Comment: If there is no error, then can you tell us what your symptoms of "not working" are, please?  Also, a link to the "asciitoshape" tool that you downloaded would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this directly in ArcGIS, there is no need for 3rd party tools. One method is to use the Make XY Event Layer (Data Management) as was suggested in a comment.

This help page provides good instructions on how to do this in ArcGIS: [Adding x,y coordinate data as a layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000001z000000)